# ASP.NET MVC 5 Error with character Ø

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, special-characters

I am trying to render a Partial View using Html.Action() which model is called KU_KFØ (it is a norwegian data model). When the main view reaches the line:

`@Html.Action("_Details", "KU_KFØ", 221)`

Where `_Details` is the name of the partial view, `KU_KFØ` is the name of the model and `221` is the item ID. It throws an System.Web.HttpException exception:

InnerException

> {"c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\733d9fe3\ae1cce86\App_Web__details.cshtml.e19bfeb9.waq0znsg.0.cs(31):
>   error CS1056: unexpected character '˜' "}

Message

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

StackTrace

> at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler
>   handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean
>   setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String
>   physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm)    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, Object
>   routeValues)    at ASP._Page_Views_Equipment_Details_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\DESARROLLO\Project\Development\Project.Web\Views\Equipment\Details.cshtml:line
>   420    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

The weirdest thing is that the application completely works with this character in database columns, rendering in views, etc. but when it comes to loading a Razor View with a model which name contains this special character, it is unable to load it.

Is there any way to make it work without changing the model name?

Thanks.

Comment: That's probably it does a call to `http:\\localhost\_Details\KU_KFØ\221` under the hood. And how url works with Ø symbol? I guess not good. Try to change `KU_KFØ` to `KU_KF%C3%98`. P.s. Sorry not web developer just my guess...

Comment: @Reniuz it is a partial view called via Html.Action, so it doesn't call it that way

Comment: It might be useful to look at the generated .cs file (given in the inner exception) to see what it's actually calling that's throwing the error.  All razor files create a .cs file behind the scenes.  This may be a case to go digging into that.

Comment: Instead of partial view and model name, shouldn't it be action name and controller name?  That would make your special character a part of the (controller) class name.

Comment: can you confirm that if you do the following in  the web.config inside the system.web , write the following `<pages validateRequest="false" /> `and then  try, I have a doubt that @Reniuz idea is correct, since in all cases partial view or view, there will be a request to the server

Comment: Did you try using `@Html.Partial`

Comment: The error seems to occur when it's trying to compile the _details partial view.  This may have nothing to do with your special character.  The error it is complaining about is that a tilde(~) is not valid in an identifier.  Look at your _details view for where that tilde might be coming from.  Look at the temporary .cs file for exactly where to look.